# Why does GIT sometimes pushes just the changes to the server and sometimes everything?

Tags: git, github

For the current project we have a repository on github. Every time I work on an issue i create a local branch and when done push it to the repo. Sometimes the push is instant and sometimes i have to wait for it to upload all the files to the repo (150MB). I'm not sure but i think that when I create a local branch work on it, in the meantime master branch gets updated and my current local is behind, the push to the server always takes a lot longer.

I branch localy using

```
git checkout -b branch_name_issue_num
```

Then when I'm done i push the changes to a new branch on the repo

```
git push origin branch_name_issue_num
```

Any ideas why does it sometimes upload all the files again?

Answer (score 1):

When 'the push is instant' most likely refers to a fast-forward merge - i.e. there have been no changes in the **remote branch** since you created a **local feature** branch off it. In this case, the `remote` simply accepts your changes and updates the branch pointer.

To quote from the [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging):

> You’ll notice the phrase "Fast forward" in that merge. Because the commit pointed to by the branch you merged in was directly upstream of the commit you’re on, Git moves the pointer forward. To phrase that another way, when you try to merge one commit with a commit that can be reached by following the first commit’s history, Git simplifies things by moving the pointer forward because there is no divergent work to merge together — this is called a "fast forward".

Regarding the second part of your question, it's difficult to understand exactly what you are asking? I *think* you're pushing your local feature branch and creating a remote feature branch but I don't know what you mean when you say 'why does it upload all the files again?'.

Without digging into the details, git stores files as **objects** - it has no concept of 'files' as such. If you modify an existing file, git will not store a completely new version of that file but instead a delta of the difference between the two.

Comment: When you push your changes to the origin branch_name, objects are compressed and the upload begins. In my case sometimes the push is instant (a few MB or KB probably) , and sometimes git uploads 150MB. .That's odd to me, because I've had only a few files modified, and it should upload only the modified files(objects in git's internals). Sometimes it happens that way, sometimes it just uploads 150MB which is the size of the project folder. It seems absurd to me that it uploads everything when so little is changed.